# SQL - Performing additional math calculations on results obtained from aggregate functions within a query

Tags: sqlite, subquery, aggregate-functions

I am fairly new to writing SQL queries. I have used a subquery so that I could obtain the results of aggregate functions applied to 2 different tables. Furthermore, I would like to obtain the ratio between the results from these 2 aggregate functions. In other words, Result of Aggregate function 1 / Result of Aggregate function 2.

INPUT:
TABLE USERS

```
Id                             
1                                 
2                                 
3  
4  
5   
6  
7
```

TABLE EVENTS

```
User_Id         Event_Name  
1            View_User_Profile  
1            View_User_Activity  
1            View_User_Profile  
2            View_User_Activity  
3            View_User_Activity  
4            View_User_Profile  
5            View_User_Activity  
7            View_User_Activity
```

This is my code so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Number_of_Users, 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT U.Id) AS Number_of_Users_Viewed_Profile
    FROM dsv1069.Users U Left Join dsv1069.Events E
    ON U.Id = E.user_id
    WHERE E.Event_Name = 'view_user_profile') AS Number_of_Users_Viewed_Profile
FROM dsv1069.Users
```

RESULTS:

```
Number_of_Users: 7
Number_of_Users_Viewed_Profile: 2
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Number_of_Users: 7
Number_of_Users_Viewed_Profile: 2
PERCENT OF USERS VIEWED PROFILE: 28.6%
```

---

---

**ISSUE:** What my code doesn't do so far is calculate the ratio 2/7 = 28.6%
I have done lots of searches on aggregate functions but can't find any information on how to use the results from those functions as part of the query. Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Please add input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can obtain the column `Number_of_Users_Viewed_Profile` without the join:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM dsv1069.Events 
WHERE Event_Name = 'view_user_profile'
```

So this is equivalent to your query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS Number_of_Users, 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) 
    FROM dsv1069.Events 
    WHERE Event_Name = 'View_User_Profile'
  ) AS Number_of_Users_Viewed_Profile 
FROM dsv1069.Users
```

You can get the `ratio` column with a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS Number_of_Users, 
    (
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) 
      FROM Events 
      WHERE Event_Name = 'View_User_Profile'
    ) AS Number_of_Users_Viewed_Profile 
  FROM Users
)
SELECT *, ROUND(100.0 * Number_of_Users_Viewed_Profile / Number_of_Users, 1) AS ratio
FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tvdzH8oefNcRe3GTdNTqJ9/1).
Or without the CTE:

```
SELECT
  t1.Number_of_Users,
  t2.Number_of_Users_Viewed_Profile,
  ROUND(100.0 * t2.Number_of_Users_Viewed_Profile / t1.Number_of_Users, 1) AS ratio
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Number_of_Users FROM Users) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS Number_of_Users_Viewed_Profile 
  FROM Events 
  WHERE Event_Name = 'View_User_Profile'
) AS t2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tvdzH8oefNcRe3GTdNTqJ9/2).
Results:

```
| Number_of_Users | Number_of_Users_Viewed_Profile | ratio |
| --------------- | ------------------------------ | ----- |
| 7               | 2                              | 28.6  |
```